# How to best store credentials in a GAE app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

How could one easily store some data in a simple `GAE` Google App Engine Application? Like username or some Address information, that should be available again if the application is either restarted or redeployed due to an update.

Is `Datastore` the way to go? Or what should I have a look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) or [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide). The [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/) is actually demonstrating how to use the Datastore in case you haven't play with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I am assuming the credentials are required for connecting to other services, rather than individual credentials for lots of different users.

So on that basis if you need to change them frequently then consider the datastore.

If infrequently and you don't mind updating you code base, then leave them in the filesystem.

Other things to consider how senstive are they, who can see them.

You may have more people that have access to the datastore than can deploy/download code base (assuming you left that capability turned on) which may also be a deciding factor.